# Передача значения переменной между функциями

Tags: javascript

Как можно передать значение из одной функции в другую? Пока у меня так:

```
$( "#sss" ).click(function() {
    var itog = '111';
});
$( "#ddd" ).click(function() {
    alert(itog);
});
```

Не понимаю, почему не работает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нет доступа к переменной](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453978/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 3):

Так? :)

```
var itog;
$( "#sss" ).click(function() {
  itog = '111';
});
$( "#ddd" ).click(function() {
  alert(itog);
});
```

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если не указываем `var`, то объявляется глобальная переменная `window.itog`:

```
$( "#sss" ).click(function() {
    itog = '111';
});
$( "#ddd" ).click(function() {
    alert(itog);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Не надо так делать, минимум - можно создать себе ошибку, максимум - в строгом режиме перестанет работать. Если уж так хочется объявить что-то в глобальном объекте то тогда так: `window.foo = 5;`