# Как передать значение переменной в другую функцию

Tags: javascript

У меня есть js код который встраивается в сайты и собирает utm метки и прочую информацию.

Недавно захотел еще собирать данные Страны, Насленного пункта и Города из которого было совершено посещение.

Для этого написал код (на этом сайте мне его помогли доработать) НО! - Я никак не могу вытащить данные из функции получения данных места положения.

у меня скприпт выглядит так:

```
if(!getCookie(FIRST_VISIT_COOKIE)) // проверяем наличие куки
{   

    var date = new Date;
    var number_visit = 1; // ставим номер визита
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365); // время жизни куки
    var hash_person = rand(111111, 999999)+"."+date.getTime(); // генерируем уникальный hash посетителя
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    var site_project = location.hostname; // узнаем сайт на который установлен код
    var referrer = document.referrer; // узнаем скакой страницы пришел посетитель на сайт
    geopotision();
    sendStat();

} else {

        var hash_person = getCookie(FIRST_VISIT_COOKIE); // достаем ID посетителя из куки
        var number_visit = 2; // Выводм номер визита
        var img = document.createElement('img'); 
        var site_project = location.hostname; // узнаем сайт на который установлен код
        var referrer = document.referrer; // узнаем скакой страницы пришел посетитель на сайт
        geopotision();
        sendStat();

    }

function geopotision(){

   var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    var map;
    var city, country, region;

    function init () {

        if (typeof ymaps === 'undefined' || typeof ymaps.geolocation === 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(init, 100);
                            return;
        }

        var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;

        country = geolocation.country;
        city    = geolocation.city;
        region = geolocation.region;

    }

    init(); 
}

// отправляем статистику    
function sendStat()  {
    setTimeout(function() {
        img.src = HOST+"api/stat/?id_cabinet="+window.ucrmProjectId+"&hash_person="+hash_person+"&site_project="+site_project+"&country="+country;// отправка данных обработчику    
    }, 500);
}
```

Я честно скажу в JS плохо разбираюсь я еще не понял как правильно брать данные из функций и передавать их туда куда мне надо. **Покажите как!**

Comment: Уточните какие данные и из какой в какую функцию вы хотите их передавать?

Comment: у меня в момент хахода пользователя отправляются данные на сервер img.src = HOST+"api/stat/?id_cabinet="+window.ProjectId+"&hash_person="+hash_person+"&country="+country+"&region="+region+"&city="+city; и вот как-то засунуть сюда данные из полученных данных функции по определению местоположения.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо условие выполняемое при первом входе переместить в функцию определения положения юзера, чтобы данные о местоположении были в наличии.

Примерно так

```
// определяем страну, регион, город
function geopotision(){

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    var map;
    var city, country, region;

    function init () {

        if (typeof ymaps === 'undefined' || typeof ymaps.geolocation === 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(init, 100);
                            return;
        }

        var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;

        country = geolocation.country;
        city    = geolocation.city;
        region = geolocation.region;

        if(!getCookie(FIRST_VISIT_COOKIE)) // проверяем наличие куки
        {

            var date = new Date;
            var number_visit = 1; // ставим номер визита
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365); // время жизни куки
            var hash_person = rand(111111, 999999)+"."+date.getTime(); // генерируем уникальный hash посетителя
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            var site_project = location.hostname; // узнаем сайт на который установлен код
            var referrer = document.referrer; // узнаем скакой страницы пришел посетитель на сайт
            img.src = HOST+"api/stat/?id_cabinet="+window.ProjectId+"&hash_person="+hash_person+"&country="+country+"&region="+region+"&city="+city; // отправка данных

        }
    }
init();
}
```

**UPD** из комментариев.

1. Вынесите объявление переменных `city`, `country`, `region` в начало скрипта из функции.

   ```
   var city = "",
       country = "",
       region = "";
   ```
2. Вызов условия `if(!getCookie(FIRST_VISIT_COOKIE)) {...}` сделайте внутри отдельно функции, которую вызывайте отложенно через `setTimeout(ИМЯ_ФУНКЦИИ, 3000);`

То есть, если за 3 секунды скрипт местоположения не запишет данные в переменные `city`, `country`, `region`, то

```
img.src = HOST+"api/stat/?id_cabinet="+window.ProjectId+"&hash_person="+hash_person+"&country="+country+"&region="+region+"&city="+city; // отправка данных
```

данные уйдут для местоположения пустые.

Comment: вот немного не то. мне ни в коем случае нельзя чтобы запись данных проходила внутри функции определения место положения.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, почему нельзя этого делать?

Comment: Ну в принципе согласен, но вдруг карта яндекса не отдаст данные? тогда данные в базу не запишуться... или я немного ошибаюсь...

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, нет, не ошибаетесь.

Comment: вот по этому приоритет нужен в записи данных, а не выяснение города страны и области. Это как дополнительные данные просто. И они должны или подставляться если они есть, а если нет то ставим false

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, смотрите обновления ответа.

Comment: выложил как сделал, только все равно как-то не получается... =(

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, а почему вы объявление переменных не вынесли в начало скрипта? Я разве об этом не написал 1м пунктом?

Comment: поставил прям вверху над всем этим скриптом, записывает undefined

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, а их объявление из функции убрали? Или просто копию сделали? Тут я уже про это писал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438141/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8/438144#438144

Comment: конечно один раз объявил. Станно работать начало, смотрю базу на одном сайте установлен скрипт (клиента) зафиксировало "Россия", на своем тестирую обновлю записывает в базу undefined, задержка включения условия стояла 2000, поставил 5000 в базу записывает вообще пустоту. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, вы сами просили, чтобы данные приходили даже если скрипт местоположения не срабатывает. Так если приходит пустота, то возможно у клиента заблокирован доступ к этому скрипту, не хочет он свое местоположение вам показывать ;) Если же у вас `undefined`, то вероятно в скрипте есть ошибка, то есть переменная в каком-то случае не определена. Тестируйте, логируйте состояние переменных в браузере через инструменты разработчика.

Comment: в том то и прикол, что в панели определяет и городо и страну и регион, а в базу пишет undefined

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что это может зависит от скорости отдачи скрипта. Или скорости интернета. Потому-как когда к яндексу подключается, то это дополнительное время, а мой скрипт раньше был загружен, мне кажется может быть когда происходит расхождение то и пишет в базу undefined

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, `undefined` у вас может возвращаться, только в том случае, когда переменные не определены. А они не могут быть не определены, так как я вам посоветовал поставить их объявление перед всем кодом! Они могут возвращаться пустыми, если скрипт яндекса не отработал до того, как сработала отправка. То есть в вашем коде есть логическая ошибка на данный момент.

Comment: Все определено в самом начале, все переменные, т.е. до них вообще ничего нет кроме других определяемых переменных. на моем сайте главное пишет undefined в базу, а тот же скрипт стоит у клиента пишет все данные местоположения странно...