# Нет доступа к переменной

Tags: javascript

Не могу прочитать переменную

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var toid;
function reply(id){
var toid = id; // тут изменяем
};
</script>
```

затем выполняем другой скрипт

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$('#send').click(function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/send.php',
data: {'id': toid, .......... // тут отправляем
```

Выходит, что отправляется пустота. Почему переменная не пишется/читается?

Comment: понял, убрал второй var. не знал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо внутри функции снова объявлять переменную, если вы хотите, чтобы она у вас был видна вне функции. Объявляете ее 1 раз в глобальной области видимости

```
var toid;
function reply(id){
    toid = id; // тут изменяем
};
```